# Protractor jasmine catch exception on error/expect fail

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

We are using protractor with jasmine framework. Following is our spec file

```js
describe('Projects CRUD', function () {
 var projectsPage = require('../pages/Projects_Page.js');
    var commonFunctions = require('../utils/CommonFunctions.js');
    
    it('Rename Project - Duplicate name check', function () {
     try{
      projectsPage.clickProjectsTab();
            projectsPage.selectProject('AutoProject1');
            projectsPage.projectBreadcrumbChevron.click();
            projectsPage.editProjectIcon.click();
            projectsPage.editProjectUpdateButton.click();
            expect(projectsPage.duplicateProjectError.getText()).toEqual('A Project with that name already exists');
            projectsPage.editProjectCancelButton.click()
            commonFunctions.updateResult(164378 , "Project duplicate name checked with same Org unit successfully", "p");
     }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      commonFunctions.updateResult(164378 , err, "f");
     }
     });
});
```

Our requirement is it should execute catch block if any of the steps fails inbetween or even expect condition fails in 'it' block. Currently for any exception its not reaching to catch block.  Following the error trace

```
Failures:
 1) Projects CRUD Rename Project - Duplicate name check
 Message:
   Failed: project not found
 Stack:
 Error: project not found
    at E:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\UIAutomation\pages\Projects_Page.js:39:23
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
    at asyncRun (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
    at C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: Run it("Rename Project - Duplicate name check") in control flow
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
    at C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:64:48
    at ControlFlow.emit (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\events.js:62:21)
    at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2674:10)
    at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2599:53)
From asynchronous test:
Error
    at Suite.<anonymous> (E:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\UIAutomation\specs\ProjectsCrud.js:6:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\UIAutomation\specs\ProjectsCrud.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
```

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 30.699 seconds

Comment: Instead of using control flow, use async/await

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
it('Rename Project - Duplicate name check', async () => {
    try{
        await projectsPage.clickProjectsTab();
        await projectsPage.selectProject('AutoProject1');
        await projectsPage.projectBreadcrumbChevron.click();
        await projectsPage.editProjectIcon.click();
        await projectsPage.editProjectUpdateButton.click();
        expect(await projectsPage.duplicateProjectError.getText()).toEqual('A Project with that name already exists');
        await projectsPage.editProjectCancelButton.click();
        await commonFunctions.updateResult(164378 , "Project duplicate name checked with same Org unit successfully", "p");
    }catch(err){
        await console.log(err);
        await commonFunctions.updateResult(164378 , err, "f");
    }
 });
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: @Madhan- I tried changing control flow to async. But its showing strange error  "Semicolon expected" for await statement in editor. FYI I am using page object model.Ex-  projectsPage is a page and clickProjectTab() is a function/method.

Comment: try using async /await in you function of page file

Comment: @Saagar be aware that if your framework is already large it can be a significant effort to migrate to `async/await` and it needs to be done across all your existing code. You should not use the control flow and `async/await` together as this can cause sync issue. It is advisable to do it when you can as the control flow is being descoped but you shouldn't estimate the effort involved.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand execution flow correctly, your error occur at first row after `describe`(or even earlier) block right here

```
describe('Projects CRUD', function () {
    error is here ----> var projectsPage = require('../pages/Projects_Page.js');
    var commonFunctions = require('../utils/CommonFunctions.js');
```

before try/catch block, and so this error couldn't reach catch block.

And from error message, there something wrong in `Projects_Page.js` file, probably missing `require/import` or typo.

As a side note, read about async/await in [Proctractor documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await), because Web Driver Control Flow, as far as i know, already disabled by default.

Comment: @RedVarVar- Error occurs in projectsPage.selectProject('AutoProject1'); line. I intentionally made it to fail to check try catch block. As mentioned in main thread its not executing catch block